# Format/Safe string for "title" attribute in anchor

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, string-formatting

I have a function that builds an anchor tag. The function recieves the URL, Title as parameters. The problem is that sometime the text includes quotation marks and this results in a anchor tag generated with syntax errors.

Which is the best way to solve this problems? Is there any function that parses the text into a safe string, in this case, for the title attribute.

Otherwise I can check the string and strip all quotation marks, but I would like know if there is a better way to do this, e.g there might be some other characters that can crash my function as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually you want to use [HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdek0zbf.aspx) to encode your title attribute. The other encoders will do more work (and have different uses) whereas this one only escapes ", &, and < to generate a valid text for an attribute.

Example:
`This is a <"test"> & something else.` becomes `This is a &lt;&quot;Test&quot;> &amp; something else.`

Comment: I am using a custom function that I build to generate my anchor tag. Is there any function in the library I can use instead, it might be a better and safe approach. Thanks

Comment: It depends on the complexity, you can use the `HtmlTextWriter` class to generate valid HTML. It's quite heavy for simple stuff though... I only use it when rendering complicated controls and such. If you use the `HtmlTextWriter` approach, you can generate it in memory by using a `StringBuilder` object, wrapping that in a `TextWriter` object, then having the `HtmlTextWriter` write to that - and grab the HTML via the `StringBuilder.ToString()` method. Also, if you use the `HtmlTextWriter` method, be sure to add the attribute before rendering the begin tag. (It may be simpler to do it by hand) :)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I guess in this case it's better to do it by hand, cheers

Comment: Chrome displays This is a &lt;&quot;Test&quot;> when hovering